# Printing hexadecimal characters in C

Tags: c, hex, printf

I'm trying to read in a line of characters, then print out the hexadecimal equivalent of the characters.

For example, if I have a string that is `"0xc0 0xc0 abc123"`, where the first 2 characters are `c0` in hex and the remaining characters are `abc123` in ASCII, then I should get

```
c0 c0 61 62 63 31 32 33
```

However, `printf` using `%x` gives me

```
ffffffc0 ffffffc0 61 62 63 31 32 33
```

How do I get the output I want without the `"ffffff"`? And why is it that only c0 (and 80) has the `ffffff`, but not the other characters?

Comment: The string that matches your array of bytes would be... ```"\xc0\xc0abc123"```

Answer (score 169, accepted):

You are seeing the `ffffff` because `char` is signed on your system. In C, vararg functions such as `printf` will promote all integers smaller than `int` to `int`. Since `char` is an integer (8-bit signed integer in your case), your chars are being promoted to `int` via sign-extension.

Since `c0` and `80` have a leading 1-bit (and are negative as an 8-bit integer), they are being sign-extended while the others in your sample don't.

```
char    int
c0 -> ffffffc0
80 -> ffffff80
61 -> 00000061
```

Here's a solution:

```
char ch = 0xC0;
printf("%x", ch & 0xff);
```

This will mask out the upper bits and keep only the lower 8 bits that you want.

Comment: My solution using a cast to `unsigned char` is one instruction smaller in gcc4.6 for x86-64...

Comment: Maybe I can help. This is (technically) undefined behavior because specifier `x` requires an unsigned type, but ch is promoted to int. The correct code would simply cast ch to unsigned, or use a cast to unsigned char and the specifier: `hhx`.

Comment: If I have `printf("%x", 0)`, nothing is printed.

Comment: It doesn't print anything because the minimum is set to 0. To fix this, try `printf("%.2x", 0);` which will boost the minimum characters drawn to 2. To set a max, prepend the . with a number. For example, you can force only 2 characters drawn by doing `printf("%2.2x", 0);`

Comment: Any reason why `printf("%x", ch & 0xff)` should be better than just using `printf("%02hhX", a)` as in @brutal_lobster's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8060262/427158)?

Answer (score 75):

Indeed, there is type conversion to int.
Also you can force type to char by using %hhx specifier.

```
printf("%hhX", a);
```

In most cases you will want to set the minimum length as well to fill the second character with zeroes:

```
printf("%02hhX", a);
```

ISO/IEC 9899:201x says:

> 7 The length modifiers and their meanings are:
>   hh Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a
>   signed char or unsigned char argument (the argument will have
>   been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall be
>   converted to signed char or unsigned char before printing); or that
>   a following

Answer (score 30):

You can create an unsigned char:

```
unsigned char c = 0xc5;
```

Printing it will give `C5` and not `ffffffc5`.

Only the chars bigger than 127 are printed with the `ffffff` because they are negative (char is signed).

Or you can cast the `char` while printing:

```
char c = 0xc5; 
printf("%x", (unsigned char)c);
```

Comment: +1 the real best answer, explicit typing as close to the data declaration as possible (but not closer).

Answer (score 18):

You can use `hh` to tell [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) that the argument is an unsigned char. Use `0` to get zero padding and `2` to set the width to 2. `x` or `X` for lower/uppercase hex characters.

```
uint8_t a = 0x0a;
printf("%02hhX", a); // Prints "0A"
printf("0x%02hhx", a); // Prints "0x0a"
```

---

**Edit**: If readers are concerned about 2501's assertion that this is somehow not the 'correct' format specifiers I suggest they read the [`printf` link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) again. Specifically:

> Even though %c expects int argument, it is safe to pass a char because of the integer promotion that takes place when a variadic function is called.
>
> The correct conversion specifications for the fixed-width character types (int8_t, etc) are defined in the header `<cinttypes>`(C++) or `<inttypes.h>` (C) **(although PRIdMAX, PRIuMAX, etc is synonymous with %jd, %ju, etc)**.

As for his point about signed vs unsigned, in this case it does not matter since the values must always be positive and easily fit in a signed int. There is no signed hexideximal format specifier anyway.

**Edit 2**: ("when-to-admit-you're-wrong" edition):

If you read [the actual C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) on page 311 (329 of the PDF) you find:

> hh: Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a `signed char` or `unsigned char` argument (the argument will have been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall be converted to `signed char` or `unsigned char` before printing); or that a following `n` conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a `signed char` argument.

Comment: Specifiers are not correct for the type uint8_t. Fixed width types use special print specifiers. See: `inttypes.h`

Comment: Yeah but all varargs integers are implicitly promoted to int.

Comment: That may be, but as far as C is defined, behavior is undefined if you don't use the correct specifier.

Comment: But %x *is* the correct specifier. (`char` and `unsigned char` are promoted to `int`)[http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments]. You would only need to use the PRI specifiers for things that don't fit in your platform `int` - e.g. `unsigned int`.

Comment: `%x` is correct for unsigned int not int. Types char and unsigned char are promoted to int. In addition there is no guarantee that uint8_t is defined as unsigned char.

Comment: See my edit. There is no signed hex specifier. It is perfectly value to promote `uint8_t` to `int`. QED.

Comment: You didn't address my comments. *There is no signed hex specifier.* Exactly, int cannot be printed using specifier `x`. Only unsigned int.The quote you posted is not from the C Standard. Therefore it is not relevant.

Comment: As I have already written, you assume that uint8_t is always defined as unsigned char. This is not the case as C makes no such guarantee.

Answer (score 14):

You are probably storing the value 0xc0 in a `char` variable, what is probably a signed type, and your value is negative (most significant bit set). Then, when printing, it is converted to `int`, and to keep the semantical equivalence, the compiler pads the extra bytes with 0xff, so the negative `int` will have the same numerical value of your negative `char`. To fix this, just cast to `unsigned char` when printing:

```
printf("%x", (unsigned char)variable);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably printing from a signed char array. Either print from an unsigned char array or mask the value with 0xff: e.g. ar[i] & 0xFF. The c0 values are being sign extended because the high (sign) bit is set.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
int main()
{
    printf("%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x\n",
        0xC0, 0xC0, 0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33);
}
```

Which produces this:

```
$ ./foo 
c0 c0 61 62 63 31 32 33
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an program to help illustrate sign extension. Note that 0 - 127 (0 to 0111 1111) in hex shows as expected, because the sign bit is 0, so when going from 8-bit to 32-bit its extended with 0's (which show as blank in the hex). Once you get to 128 (1000 000) signed char, it becomes a negative number (-128), and it is sign-extended with 1's / F's.

```
                 unsigned    signed        hex    binary
-----------------------------------------------------------
unsigned char:        127       127         7f    0111 1111
  signed char:        127       127         7f    0111 1111

                 unsigned    signed         hex   binary
---------------------------------------------------------------
unsigned char:        128        128         80   00000000 00000000 00000000 10000000
  signed char:        ...       -128   ffffff80   11111111 11111111 11111111 10000000
```

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(char c) {
    unsigned char uc = c;
    printf("               %15s %15s %15s\n", "unsigned", "signed", "hex");
    printf("---------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("unsigned char: %15u %15i %15x\n", uc, uc, uc);
    printf("  signed char: %15u %15i %15x\n\n", c, c, c);
}

void main() {
    print(127);
    print(128);
}
```

Unsigned char gets extended with 0's even when going over 127, because you've explicitly told it that its a positive number.

When printing the signed char, as a signed integer, you can see how sign-extending is preserving the value of -128.

(edit: added binary column to the example output, will include this in the program code later)