# How to print a byte as a two-digit hexadecimal character?

Tags: c, printf

I need to generate random GUIDs in C, in Windows. I have:

```
HCRYPTPROV hCryptProv = 0;
BYTE pbBuffer[16];
int i;
if (!CryptAcquireContextW(&hCryptProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT | CRYPT_SILENT))
    exit(1);
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    if (!CryptGenRandom(hCryptProv, 16, pbBuffer))
        exit(1);
    printf("%X%X%X%X-%X%X-%X%X-%X%X-%X%X%X%X%X%X\n", pbBuffer[0], pbBuffer[1], pbBuffer[2], pbBuffer[3],
                                                     pbBuffer[4], pbBuffer[5], pbBuffer[6], pbBuffer[7],
                                                     pbBuffer[8], pbBuffer[9], pbBuffer[10], pbBuffer[11],
                                                     pbBuffer[12], pbBuffer[13], pbBuffer[14], pbBuffer[15]);
}
```

However, this prints any byte less than 0F as a single character (e.g., `0000-00-00-00-000000` if each `pbBuffer[j]` were `0`). I need every single byte printed to be two characters (e.g., `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` if each `pbBuffer[j]` were `0`). How can I do this?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060170/printing-hexadecimal-characters-in-c

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try `printf("%02X", an_integer)`.  The `02X` says to zero-fill to two display characters.