# Strange issue with string to hex code

Tags: c, parsing, hex

I wrote some code to apply a patch to a binary file, the patches are delimited ascii representations of hexadecimal values, like so: 00FF00:A155F3;9210BC.

My problem is that I'm miscalculating the value of a hexadecimal by exactly 256, but only between the delimiters ':' and ';' since I use the same hex2char() function regardless of position within the code, I can't figure out why it's failing in this one specific area. I figured instead of wasting too much time on it, I'll sign up for stackoverflow and get some help.

I don't want to use any external libraries, I don't want to include anything other than stdio.h and stdlib.h (I'll remove sys/stat.h, and fread() and realloc() until EOF, but that's another problem and i'm not concerned about it)

here is the code, my main loop is way near the end and I clearly mark where I get the bad output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>


//I'll populate this later
struct _pos {
    unsigned pos;
} pos;


//raise x to the power of y
unsigned power( unsigned x, unsigned y )
{
    if ( y == 0 )
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return x * power( x, y - 1 );
    }
}

//convert ascii hex values to integers
unsigned h2i(const char *input, int len) {
    unsigned retval = 0;
    char cur = 0;
    int loops = 0;
    while (0 < len) {
        cur = input[--len];
        //check if we are out of the range hex would be in
        //we assume capital letters A - F
        if ( cur < 0x30 || cur > 0x46 ) {
            printf("Hex out of range: %X\n", cur);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        //numerical
        if ( cur < 0x3a ) {
            cur -= 0x30;
        }

        //alphabetical
        else {
            cur -= 0x37;
        }

        retval += (cur * power(16, loops));
        ++loops;
        }
    return retval;
}

//take 2 chars from the input and get a hex value from it
char hex2char(const char *input) {
    char buff[2];
    buff[0] = input[pos.pos++];
    buff[1] = input[pos.pos++];
    printf("\nBUFF: %c%c : POS: %i\n", buff[0], buff[1], pos.pos);
    return h2i(buff, 2);
}


//turn a delimiter terminated string into a number
unsigned hex2int(const char *input, char delimiter) {
    int offset = 0;
    char buff[13]; //max int length if represented by string

    //copy string into the buffer
    while (input[offset] != delimiter) {
        if (offset == 12) {
            printf("parse error: offset\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        buff[offset] = input[offset];
        ++offset;
    }
   //printf("BUFF: %s : OFFSET: %i\n", buff, offset);
    pos.pos += offset;
    return h2i(buff, offset);

}

char *fast_cache( char *Filename, unsigned long *size ) {
    FILE *FilePointer;
    FilePointer = fopen( Filename, "r" );
    if ( FilePointer != NULL ) {
        char *ptr;
        struct stat FileStat;
        fstat( fileno( FilePointer ), &FileStat );
        *size = FileStat.st_size;
        ptr = ( char * ) malloc( *size );
        fread( ptr, 1, *size, FilePointer );
        fclose( FilePointer );
        return ptr;
        }
    else {
        return NULL;
        }
    }


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // print greeting
    printf("Hello World!\n");

    unsigned long size;
    char *file = fast_cache(argv[1], &size);
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("You must specify an input!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //okay, patchfile found, opened, and cached, time to convert
    pos.pos = 0; //file position

    //this will be the output, unused right now
    FILE *out = fopen("output", "w");
    //a line in the file is formatted like this
    //0000FF:A9DF23;A7FF11
    unsigned fileoffset = 0;
    unsigned trash = 0;


    //loop through all lines in the patchfile
    while (pos.pos < size) {
        fileoffset = hex2int(file, 0x3a);
        ++pos.pos;
        printf("offset: %u CUR: %c\n", fileoffset, file[pos.pos]);
        while(file[pos.pos] != 0x3b ) {
            //check current values with file values
            //not implimented yet, i just print it out

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////This is the issue right here///////////////////////////
//printf prints a near MAX_INT number hex value > 0xFFFFFF00
//and it is off by exactly 256 every time, but that would mean overflowing
            printf("%X ", hex2char(file));

        }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//but right here until EOF, everything is fine and works normally
//and it's the same freaking function

        printf("\nfound delimiter: %c @ %u\n", file[pos.pos], pos.pos);
        ++pos.pos;

        //second half of the line
        while(file[pos.pos] != '\n' && pos.pos < size) {
            printf("%X ", hex2char(file));
        }
        //eat the new line if there is one
        ++pos.pos;
        printf("\nLine complete\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have some particularly good reason to do the conversion yourself instead of using `fscanf` with the `%x` conversion, or reading a string and converting with `strtol`?

Comment: Your hex2char function seems to be returning an 16 bit integer where it is supposed to return 8 bit character. Is it what you want?

Comment: @jerry I could use fscanf, but I'm attempting to create my own conversion function as a learning exercise which will come in handy when I have the need to create the same code as above, but in assembly on a CPU that doesn't have a C compiler, eg DCPU-16

Comment: @mihirj oops, i forgot to cast it to char, unfortunately a quick recompile yields the same results.

Comment: A minor nitpick, but could you please come up with a more descriptive title? That you have a strange issue with some code, doesn't really tell us anything about the problem you're trying to solve/tackle. Most people here have a strange issue with their code. ;)

Comment: @bart I'm sorry, I'm still not sure how to classify this, it was between 'strange issue' and 'function gives bad result with different input' neither of which are good summaries...

Comment: Can you post your test input file ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UDtp7Jwt I've been using just two test lines so far

Comment: The error is that it is printing FFs before the number?

Comment: yes, that is my error, I don't understand why it does that though if the source is a char and it prints the right value about half the time

Comment: I posted a few links that explain this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using printf in C, your chars will be promoted to ints. As they are unsigned chars, you have to mask the remaining bits.

Replace:

```
printf("%X ", hex2char(file));
```

with:

```
printf("%X ", hex2char(file) & 0xff);
```

You can find a complete description of this problem here:
[Printing hexadecimal characters in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060170/printing-hexadecimal-characters-in-c)
and here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension

If you have to implement this in assembly, I recommend replacing your pow function by a simple bit shifting operation. X << 4 == X * 16. Also pay attention that on microcontrollers or other embedded systems, you can find a 16 bit system. In this case, the size of your int can be different.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much! Oddly enough I've never run into this problem before but a quick check shows that it was my problem, i've made sure all of my values are cleaned with "& 0xff" after the function, and now I can get to the rest of my program, and the optimizing part.

Answer (score 2):

Your code to convert string to integer is ... fantastically complicated, for what it does.

It's really overkill to involve a (recursive!) function like `power()` when all you need is something like `x <<= 4` to shift the value to the left by 4 bits.

Without going into too much detail in your code, try replacing your hex string to integer function with something like:

```
/* Parse hexadecimal number at s into value stored in v. Returns pointer to first
 * character that is not part of the number. Doesn't protect against overflow.
*/
const char * parse_int_hex(const char *s, unsigned long *v)
{
  *v = 0;
  for(; ; s++ )
  {
    char here = *s;
    unsigned long dv;
    if( here >= '0' && here <= '9' )
      dv = here - '0';
    else if( here >= 'a' && here <= 'f' )
      dv = 10 + here - 'a';
    else if( here >= 'A' && here <= 'F' )
      dv = 10 + here - 'A';
    else
      return s;
    *v <<= 4;
    *v += dv;
  }
  return s;
}
```

The above has no dependencies, which is why the character-checking is so tedious. :) This is about the size you would expect for a plain hex-to-integer conversion routine.

Comment: Thanks for optimizing the parsing function, your code looks like the c code I hope to write eventually, but as nmenezes stated, it was a sign extension problem that was giving me trouble.