# Why does this output seem non-deterministic? (Is it the sprintf, printf, or syntax of hexadecimal literals?)

Tags: c++, debugging, printf, hex

#### tl;dr

Why do I get different output every time I run this code ([Ideone](http://ideone.com/K5Rou9)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    const char* _user = "FOO";
    const char* _password = "BAR";

    char login[21];
    sprintf(login,
        "\x15\x00\x01%-8s%-10s",
        _user,
        _password);

    for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
        printf(" %02x", login[i] & 0xff);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But not this code ([Ideone](http://ideone.com/1niFYa)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    const char* _user = "FOO";
    const char* _password = "BAR";
    const char* _session = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
    int _expectedSeq = 123;

    char login[38];
    sprintf(login,
            "L%-6s%-10s%10s%10d\xA",
            _user,
            _password,
            _session,
            _expectedSeq);

    for (int i = 0; i < 38; i++) {
        printf(" %02x", login[i] & 0xff);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

#### Question

Deep in our application code, I came across this:

```
char login[38];
sprintf(login,
        "L%-6s%-10s%10s%10d\xA",
        _user,
        _password,
        _session,
        _expectedSeq);
```

Now, I need to write a (simpler) variant of this code:

```
char login[21];
sprintf(login,
       "\x15\x00\x01%-8s%-10s",
       _user,
       _password);
```

Somehow, this doesn't work! What's weird is that the latter produces different results every time.

---

#### Thoughts

1. The former example only has a hex literal at the end. Is this masking the issue in the former's case?
2. Or, am I actually messing up my debug output, `printf`? (By the way, I got the `& 0xff` thing from [Printing hexadecimal characters in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060170/printing-hexadecimal-characters-in-c).)
3. Could it have something to do with using `char` instead of `unsigned char`? But then, why does the former case work?

Comment: Wouldn't a null character `"\x00"` mean that your format string is terminated prematurely?  (Considering `sprintf` only understands null-terminated strings…)

Comment: Addition to the answer below: Without termination, your `login` would be too short to hold everything -> undefined behaviour ("if" this was the case). (Well, now it´s in the answer too)

Comment: btw, you're overrunning your array bounds in the first one. The line array is 38 chars long, meaning 37+1 (the 1 being the terminator, the 37 being the allowed maximum length). The sample output you linked is 38 printed bytes, meaning you're sprintf is writing **39** including the terminator, thereby invoking UB.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, `sprintf` doesn't null terminate automatically, so in our case we're okay. That buffer is fed directly to a network handle to which we also pass the number of bytes to send, _i.e._ 21 or 38. (Not saying I think this is how things should be done—just how things are. We don't even use `bool` because it didn't exist when my company started.)

Comment: @AndrewCheong Wrong, the termination is required. Look at eg. N1570, 7.21.6.6.2

Comment: 'sprintf' definitely will terminate. 'snprintf' won't null terminate if the max length is reached and that might be what is confusing?

Comment: @deviantfan - Ah, you're right. Looks like we're writing past the memory space then. Oops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your string literal has an embedded NUL byte, and that marks the end of the string as far as `sprintf` is concerned. So your call is identical to:

```
sprintf(login,
       "\x15",
       _user,
       _password);
```

And that writes into the `login` array only two bytes: `0x15 0x00`.

There are several approaches to solve this mixing of bytes and characters. My choice would be something along the lines of:

```
memcpy(login, "\x15\x00\x01", 3);
sprintf(login + 3,
   "%-8s%-10s",
   _user,
   _password);
```

The call to `memcpy` takes as parameter the number of bytes, so it is immune to the embedded NUL problem.

But note that `sprintf` automaticall adds a NUL byte at the end of the output string, so you actually need 22 bytes: 3 + 8 + 10 + 1 = 22:

```
char login[22];
```

Comment: That was precisely it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that second format string contains a null character (`\x00`) which terminates it prematurely. Change the string to use `%c` instead and have a null character printed there.