# Print character array as hex in C

Tags: c, arrays, hex, converters, radix

I have a 2D array called `char **str` (allocated by malloc). Lets say str[0] has the string "hello". How would I print that hex?

I tried `printf("%d\n", (unsigned char)strtol(str[0], NULL, 16))`, but that doesn't print it out in hex.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing hexadecimal characters in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060170/printing-hexadecimal-characters-in-c)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are confused about the fuctionality of `strtol`. If you have a string that represents a number in hex, you can use `strtol` like you have:

```
char s[] = "ff2d";
int n = strtol(s, NULL, 16);
printf("Number: %d\n", n);
```

When you want to print the characters of a string in hex, use `%x` format specifier for each character of the string.

```
char s[] = "Hello";
char* cp = s;
for ( ; *cp != '\0'; ++cp )
{
   printf("%02x", *cp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But what does the 2 do in `%2x`? If I take it out, it still prints the same hex.

Comment: It means use a width of 2 to print the number. It should really be `%02x` so that it prints a leading zero if the number is less than 16.

Answer (score 5):

> Use %x flag to print hexadecimal integer

**example.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
  char *string = "hello", *cursor;
  cursor = string;
  printf("string: %s\nhex: ", string);
  while(*cursor)
  {
    printf("%02x", *cursor);
    ++cursor;
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
$ ./example 
string: hello
hex: 68656c6c6f
```

---

**reference**

- [printf reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)
- [ascii table](http://www.ascii-code.com/)

Comment: Thank you as well! The links really helped and always nice to see different ways to do the same thing. Also, the same question above what does the 02 do in `%02x`?

Comment: 02 is just zeropadding so in the event the hexadecimal integer was less than 2 bytes long eg. 9 then it would print 09.. not really required for the alpha characters as these are all in the two byte hexadecimal range

Comment: Can you explain the *cursor* thing? Also, this will give you compiler error unless you change `*string` to `string[]`.