# Printing in HEX: program adds additional 0xFFs

Tags: c, binaryfiles, fread

I'm trying to read a binary file two bytes at a time and display the result. I came up with the following:

```
int main() {
    char opcode[2];
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("games/PONG", "rb");

    while( fread(opcode, 1, 2, fp) != 0 ) {
        printf(" %02X%02X\n", opcode[0], opcode[1]);
    }
}
```

It sort of works:

```
$ ./c8disas
 6A02
 6B0C
 6C3F
 6D0C
 FFFFFFA2FFFFFFEA
 FFFFFFDAFFFFFFB6
 FFFFFFDCFFFFFFD6
 6E00
 ...
```

Some of the lines in the output contain additional `FF` bytes, and I don't understand where they come from.

For reference, this is the binary I'm reading:

```
$ hexdump -C games/PONG
00000000  6a 02 6b 0c 6c 3f 6d 0c  a2 ea da b6 dc d6 6e 00  |j.k.l?m.......n.|
00000010  22 d4 66 03 68 02 60 60  f0 15 f0 07 30 00 12 1a  |".f.h.``....0...|
00000020  c7 17 77 08 69 ff a2 f0  d6 71 a2 ea da b6 dc d6  |..w.i....q......|
00000030  60 01 e0 a1 7b fe 60 04  e0 a1 7b 02 60 1f 8b 02  |`...{.`...{.`...|
00000040  da b6 60 0c e0 a1 7d fe  60 0d e0 a1 7d 02 60 1f  |..`...}.`...}.`.|
...
```

Comment: Try reading into an `unsigned char` instead. Values greater than or equal to `0x80` are sign-extended with `char` here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing hexadecimal characters in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060170/printing-hexadecimal-characters-in-c)

Comment: there were already so many duplicates here

Comment: Every integer argument smaller than 4 bytes which is passed to function `printf` is expanded to 4 bytes. When a `signed char` argument is expanded to 4 bytes, each one of the 3 added bytes is 0xFF if the value is negative, and 0x00 if the value is non-negative. You can use `%.2X` if you want `printf` to avoid printing those 3 bytes. Alternatively, you can declare the argument as `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 3):

`char` is normally a signed integer by default. So the high order bits are sign extended when it's widened to an `int` before being passed to `printf()`. Use `unsigned char` instead.

You can also AND (`&`) with `0xff` to strip off other bits but you really should be using an unsigned value here.

Answer (score 2):

The FFs come from the negative bit (I know it %X is supposed to be unsigned). Try:

```
printf(" %02X%02X\n", 0xFF & opcode[0], 0xFF & opcode[1]);
```

Comment: Have you tried this code? I doubt that it would make any difference.

Comment: @barakmanos I tried. It worked. Here the integer promotion is happening when performing `&`, so `0xFF` is expanded to `0x00..0FF`.