# Ouptut PIN from a MAC address using char

Tags: c, char, mac-address, wiimote

I am absolutly not doing C, but for a small thing, I need to make a very simple function.
I have problem understanding the result.

I have a MAC address and I need to output the PIN code. (wiimote) I got this function so far

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char pin[6];
pin[0] = 0x61;
pin[1] = 0xC7;
pin[2] = 0x5E;
pin[3] = 0x00;
pin[4] = 0x9E;
pin[5] = 0xCC;
printf(pin);
return 0;
}
```

Problem is that I get as a result: **aヌ^**
Is it what I am supposed to get? Value should be different?

The point as David Hoelzer said, I might find a solution converting Hexa to string?

Thank you!

Comment: Regardless of @mohan's answer, you will still only see three characters.  These are hexadecimal values, only two of which look to be typical printable ASCII.  The fourth one (`pin[3]`) is a null, which will terminate your string.  This data is not intended to be printed as a string.

Comment: A MAC is a 6 byte address, not a printable string.

Comment: I see, so I need to convert this hexadecimal value to a string? which will display something normal?

Comment: `Is it what I am supposed to get?` well, it is your program so you should know what you expect. When you know what you want, you can get help.

Comment: You are right, but since I am not understanding C, I don't know what printf should return. I know what I want (a PIN code), but not what I am doing.

Comment: How do the PIN code look? Show example of expected output.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060170/printing-hexadecimal-characters-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
unsigned char pin[6];   // Unsigned ...
pin[0] = 0x61;
pin[1] = 0xC7;
pin[2] = 0x5E;
pin[3] = 0x00;
pin[4] = 0x9E;
pin[5] = 0xCC;

printf("%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n",pin[0],pin[1],pin[2],pin[3],pin[4],pin[5]);
```

will print

```
61:c7:5e:00:9e:cc
```

Explanation:

```
%x   // Print a number in hexadecimal format using lower case (%X for upper case)
%2x  // Print at least 2 characters (prepend with space)
%02x // Print at least 2 characters and prepend with 0
```

Use `unsigned char pin[6]` to avoid sign extention during print. If you use `char pin[6]` you'll get

```
61:ffffffc7:5e:00:ffffff9e:ffffffcc
```

which is probably not what you want.

If you for some reason need to use `char`, you can do:

```
char pin[6];
pin[0] = 0x61;
pin[1] = 0xC7;
pin[2] = 0x5E;
pin[3] = 0x00;
pin[4] = 0x9E;
pin[5] = 0xCC;

printf("%02hhx:%02hhx:%02hhx:%02hhx:%02hhx:%02hhx\n",pin[0],pin[1],pin[2],pin[3],pin[4],pin[5]);
           ^^
           Force type to char
```