# How to print 1 byte with printf?

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

I know that when using `%x` with `printf()` we are printing 4 bytes (an `int` in hexadecimal) from the stack. But I would like to print only 1 byte. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: You ought to tag the language. Is this C?

Comment: Your assumption is not correct. `printf("%x", x)` prints the value of `x` in hexadecimal form. The size of `x` is assumed to be of type `(int)`, but it's not necessarily 4 bytes.

Comment: I've added the C tag. I *think* my answer is correct, please downvote if it isn't.

Comment: _only one byte_ can you elaborate? is it a `char` variable? or is it that you want to print only one byte of a larger variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing hexadecimal characters in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060170/printing-hexadecimal-characters-in-c)

Answer (score 26):

*Assumption:You want to print the value of a variable of 1 byte width, i.e., `char`*.

In case you have a `char` variable say, `char x = 0;` and want to print the value, use `%hhx` format specifier with `printf()`.

Something like

```
 printf("%hhx", x);
```

Otherwise, due to default argument promotion, a statement like

```
  printf("%x", x);
```

would also be correct, as `printf()` will not read the `sizeof(unsigned int)` from *stack*, the value of `x` will be read based on it's type and the it will be promoted to the required type, anyway.

Comment: or `%02hhx` if you want to print the leading 0 for fixed width

Answer (score 10):

You need to be careful how you do this to avoid any *undefined behaviour*.

The C standard allows you to cast the `int` to an `unsigned char` then print the byte you want using *pointer arithmetic*:

```
int main()
{
    int foo = 2;
    unsigned char* p = (unsigned char*)&foo;
    printf("%x", p[0]); // outputs the first byte of `foo`
    printf("%x", p[1]); // outputs the second byte of `foo`
}
```

Note that `p[0]` and `p[1]` are converted to the wider type (the `int`), prior to displaying the output.

Comment: Nice.  Suggest a separator though to not mash output together.  Only corner problem is with rare `sizeof(int) == 1`.  Maybe use `for (size_t i = 0; i< sizeof foo; i++) printf("%x\n", p[i]);` to print all bytes - even if there is only 1.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following solution to print one byte with `printf`:

```
unsigned char c = 255;
printf("Unsigned char: %hhu\n", c);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print a single byte that is present in a larger value type, you can mask and/or shift out the required value. For example:

```
int x = 0x12345678; 
x & 0x00FF0000 >> 16
```

Another option is to retrieve the required byte by casting the needed byte location using a (unsigned) char pointer and using an offset.