# Why one char character appears on 4 bytes in C language

Tags: c

I am coding a C code and I want to compare the hexadecimal value of some character with an other. That is working, but with somme value like `�` I obtained a value on 4 bytes which create a no sense in my comparaison.

```c
void obs_text(char* start, unsigned char debugLevel, unsigned char depth){
    printf("%c -> 0x%x\n", start[0], start[0]);
}
```

I expected an output with two hexadecimals characters but the actual output is `? -> 0xffffffef`.
Please does any one understand what happens ? Thank you for your help.

I am compiling with gcc.

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
Thread model: posix
```

but I also try on a Debian OS with the same problem

Comment: We need more information. Can you provide the code that's calling that function?

Comment: Note that `start[0]` is promoted to `int` when passed to a variadic function. If the `char` you pass is negative, so will the `int` be, which is then treated by `%x` as an unsigned value.

Comment: Try `printf("%c -> %d\n", start[0], start[0]);` and report the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `%x` means display as an unsigned integer (4 bytes) as hexadecimal. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

As noted there, you could use `%hhx` (added in C99) to get the behavior you were expecting (see more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41638772/1518546)).

Answer (score 1):

Use `%hhx` and cast the argument to `unsigned char`:

```
printf( "%c - 0x%hhx", start[0], (unsigned char) start[0] );
```

`%x` expects its corresponding argument to have type `unsigned int`.  You need to use the `hh` length modifier to tell it that you're dealing with an `unsigned char` value.

Comment: Note: `(unsigned char)` not needed.  Both `(unsigned char) start[0]` and `start[0]` are converted to an `int` before calling `printf()`.  `printf()` takes that `int` and then cast to `unsinged char` as part of the `%hhx` specifier.