# Printing hexadecimal values using C

Tags: c, hex

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#define MAXBUF 1024*1024

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char str[sizeof(MAXBUF)];
    int i;

    fp = fopen("frame1PETData.dat","r");
    if(fp == NULL){
        perror("Error opening the file");
        return -1;
    }
    if(fgets (str,sizeof(MAXBUF),fp)!= NULL)
    {
        puts(str);
        for(i =0;i<60;i++)
        {
            printf("%hhx",str[i]);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return(0);
}
```

In the following program, when i try to print the hexadecimal data from the file, the output is in the following way.

[image]

But the actual data is as shown below which is different from output data.

```
a6 d2 fe 44 3c 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 1a
78 1a 61 1a 80 1a 70 01 0c 1a cf 14 01 11 18 00
b8 05 c0 1c 03 70 15 01 12 89 00 58 06 00 24 01
21 23 01 a5 cb 00 60 06 80 64 01 b2 22 01 a7 8b
00 70 04 c0 22 00 b3 11 01 ad 87 00 d8 10 00 4a
02 24 10 01 ae fa 00 50 04 00 18 01 45 08 02 29
8a 00 90 04 00 2c 02 b6 30 02 29 a5 01 30 08 00
```

Is my program wrong? And before every byte it is appending ff byte.

Comment: You never output any newlines or spaces, so your output contains neither newlines nor spaces.  This doesn't seem very surprising.  It's also surprising the code compiles — you've commented out the definition of `MAXBUF`.  Using `sizeof(MAXBUF)` seems implausible — it is likely to be 4 or 8.  You also have problems that your `char` type is signed and your library doesn't seem to be masking negative `char` values to just 1 byte as it should with the `%hhx` format.

Comment: `sizeof(MAXBUF)`? What the h\*ck is that supposed to do?

Comment: 1) `char str[sizeof(MAXBUF)];` --> `char str[MAXBUF];`

Comment: try print with "%x", string[i] & 0xff;
Check -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060170/printing-hexadecimal-characters-in-c

Comment: 2) `if(fgets (str,sizeof(MAXBUF),fp)!= NULL)` --> `if(fgets (str, sizeof(str), fp)!= NULL)`

Comment: 3) `for(i =0;i<60;i++)
        {
            printf("%hhx",str[i]);
        }` --> `for(i = 0; str[i]; i++)
        {
            printf("%hhx", (unsigned char)str[i]); if((i+1) % 16 == 0) putchar('\n'); else putchar(' ');
        }`

Comment: Now when I am able to print without ff after doing `string[i] & 0xff` but the data now is different. It is printing in this way... `a6d200689cbe748000180002` but the actual output should be `a6 d2 fe 44 3c 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 1a
78 1a 61 1a 80 1a 70 01 0c 1a cf 14 01 11 18 00
b8 05 c0 1c 03 70 15 01 12 89 00 58 06 00 24 01
21 23 01 a5 cb 00 60 06 80 64 01 b2 22 01 a7 8b`

Comment: If `'\x00'` is included in the input data, use `fread` instead of `fgets`. And Set the file open mode to `"rb"` instead of `"r"`. (Also `"%hhx"` --> `"%02hhx"`)

Comment: But when I try to use `for(i =0;i<sizeof(MAXBUF);i++)` instead of `for(i=0;i<60;i++)`I am unable to print the data and output data is having only `a6d200`

Comment: `sizeof(MAXBUF)` is `sizeof(int)`. If you are using a 32 bit machine, it is usually 4.

Comment: @j.aug BLUEPIXY told you to use `str[i]` as the condition. `sizeof(MAXBUF)` is nonsense.

Comment: But i defined my MAXBUF as 1024*1024 ,that means does it provide a size of 1024 Bytes? So sizeof(MAXBUF) meant 1024 right?

Comment: It(1024*1024) is 1 MByte, not 1024Byte. (Also `sizeof(MAXBUF)` is `sizeof(int)`, not 1MByte). But `fgets` reads only up to linefeed. So Use `fread` instead of `fgets` or each read byte by `fgetc`.Also When `char str[MAXBUF/*1024*1024*/];` , `sizeof(str)` is 1MByte.

Comment: sample of [using fread ver.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/onJpJ4CifPRo2HPT)

Comment: `for(i =0;i<(sizeof(MAXBUF)-1);i++)`  Better to use `fread()` and then `i<(sizeof(MAXBUF)-0)`