# Problem with memory access error in C with char*

Tags: c

I can run a c programm without problems on my Linux Mint system on a other Linux system I get a memory access error.

```
void digest_message(const unsigned char *message, size_t message_len, unsigned char **digest, unsigned int *digest_len)
{
    EVP_MD_CTX *mdctx;

    if((mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create()) == NULL)
        handleErrors();
    if(1 != EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, EVP_sha1(), NULL))
        handleErrors();
    if(1 != EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, message, message_len))
        handleErrors();
    if((*digest = (unsigned char *)OPENSSL_malloc(EVP_MD_size(EVP_sha1()))) == NULL)
        handleErrors();
    if(1 != EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, *digest, digest_len))
        handleErrors();

    EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(mdctx);
}

void main ()

{
...
    const unsigned char *message= (const unsigned char*) decryptedtext;
    size_t mlen=x;
    unsigned char *digest;
    unsigned int dlen;
    digest_message(message,mlen,&digest,&dlen);

    // if i printf in a for loop i get this memmory access error 
    for(int i=0;i<dlen;i++)
        printf("%x ",digest[i]);
    }
```

I tried it with:

```
printf("%x ",digest[0]);
printf("%x ",digest[1]);
printf("%x ",digest[2]);
...
```

and got no error

Why does this happen? How can I change it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Will you please copy/paste the error message? It will help a lot in finding out what the problem is.

Comment: Also, please provide us a compilable and executable code, in order to be able to understand what is not OK. We do not need the confidential information in the code, but just what is needed for us to understand.

Comment: What happens when you step through the program with a debugger?  (And being able to step through a program with a debugger is just **another** reason why stuffing everything into one line of code like `if((*digest = (unsigned char *)OPENSSL_malloc(EVP_MD_size(EVP_sha1()))) == NULL)` is a really **BAD** idea. Given your code, you simply can not tell if a call to `EVP_MD_size()` or `EVP_sha1()` ever failed.)

Answer (score -1):

I can spot the following (potential) problems.

---

> I can run a c programm without problems on my Linux Mint

I think that it is just a happy coincidence, that you do not **see** the problems.

---

```
const unsigned char *message= (const unsigned char*) decryptedtext;
```

If `decryptedtext` is just a pointer, then accessing it further using `message` is quite a bad idea. Normally, you should have memory allocated, in order to access it.

---

```
size_t mlen=x;
```

Ideally, `mlen` should be related to the length of `message`. If `mlen` is bigger then the real length of `message`, you are in trouble (buffer overflow, memory corruption...).

---

```
unsigned int dlen;
```

How do you make sure that `dlen` is not bigger than the number of entries available in `digest`?

---

```
printf("%x ",digest[i]);
```

Why do you want to `printf` a string (`digest`) as a hexadecimal number?

### ---------------------

```
if(decryptedtext[0]==0x25 &&   //%
    decryptedtext[1]==0x50 &&  //P
    decryptedtext[2]==0x44 &&  //D
    decryptedtext[3]==0x46)    //F
{ printf("%s",decryptedtext);
  break;
}
```

This is ugly. `decryptedtext` is not a null-terminated string, therefore `printf()` will not print only 4 characters.

---

```
int x;
f = fopen("test.pdf", "w+b");
if(f == NULL) {
printf("Datei konnte nicht geoeffnet werden.\n");
}else {

while(x<decryptedtext_len)  {
    putc(decryptedtext[x],f);
    x++;
}
```

`x` is not initialized before being used.

---

```
unsigned char hasharrayone[20];
unsigned char hasharraytwo[20];
unsigned char hasharraythree[20];
```

You could have used:

```
unsigned char hasharray[3][20];
```

---

```
int xc;
file = fopen("sxxxxx-dest-cipher.bin", "w+b");
if(file == NULL) {
printf("Datei konnte nicht geoeffnet werden.\n");
}else {
while(xc<cpl)  {
    putc(cfbciphertext[xc],file);
    xc++;
}
```

`xc` is not initialized.

Comment: I have a bin file and i want to compare something so hex is helpful. The function digest_message gives dlen the value.

Comment: OK, but the buffer is longer than 1 character, I assume. That `printf()` only prints 1 hex code.

Answer (score -1):

You have an undefined behavior using `printf("%x ", digest[i])`.

As mentionned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16864590/11502610) using the wrong format specifier results in an undefined behavior. This is probably why the behavior of your program depends on the OS you are running on (it may also depend of your hardware and compiler).

As I don't have the error message, it's hard to know what happens in your case, but as "%x" format specifier usually works with `unsigned int` it should reads 4bytes in memory. As `disgest[i]` is a `unsigned char`, it is written on 1byte only and this is probably why you get a memory access error.

Converting your `unsigned char` variable `digest[i]` to an `unsigned int` before using `printf` should resolve your issue.

Also, [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060170/printing-hexadecimal-characters-in-c) should help you printing hexadecimal characters

Comment: Because of default argument promotions that happen to arguments passed to the variable argument list, the  rvalue `digetst[i]` is implicitly converted from `unsigned char` to `int`. Because of this `%x` should work [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions)

Comment: @KamilCuk Good point didn't know about it. Though, `digetst[i]` refers to a part of the memory so it should not be an rvalue but an lvalue, am I wrong ? Is there any possibility this fact change anything ? I mean... Is it possible to implicitely type convert an lvalue ?

Comment: C doesn't really have any distinction between "lvalue" and "rvalue". "lvalue" is just an expression that can be assigned to. "rvalue" means just a "value of an expression". In C++ there happens something called "lvalue to rvalue conversion" and some other magic, in C it's more or less meaningless. In C "rvalue" is more like a jargon. The `digest[i]` is an lvalue, for sure, cause the `*` operator. I meant to say "rvalue" only meaning "the value of the `digest[i]` expression". The only place "rvalue" term is ever used in C is only [in a note](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note64).