# How to fully print a number in hexadecimal to the terminal?

Tags: c, hex, printf

I have unsigned 16-bit number that I need to print in hexadecimal to the terminal like this:

```
0x0FFE
```

But using `printf("0x%X\n", number");` I'm get this:

```
0xFFE
```

Is there way to fully print number in hexadecimal on C or C++?

Comment: What type is the "I have 16-bit number"?  If  some _signed_ type, then `"0x%04X\n", number` is insufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, leading zeros are not printed.  To print at least 4 characters with leading zeros, use the `0` flag and a field width of 4.

```
printf("0x%04X\n", number);
```

Comment: probably duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060170/printing-hexadecimal-characters-in-c