# What is the storage size of each address?

Tags: c, memory

I had expected each memory address contain 1-byte data. But on below code, I getting 4-byte hex value. Why this happened?

<sub>*I'm aware of negative `int`  representation*.</sub>

```
char num = -25;
char *ptr = &num;
printf("%02X", *ptr);
```

`Output : FFFF FFE7`

`Expected : E7`

<sub>Edit : Another good answer in here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8060195/17823490</sub>

Comment: If `I'm aware of negative int  representation.` why are you asking the question? `*ptr` is being converted to a 4-byte `int`.  If you don't want this, do this: `printf("%02X", (uint8_t)*ptr);`.

Comment: %X prints unsigned int as a hexadecimal number. x uses lower-case letters and X uses upper-case.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel: with C-variadic ellipsis, there are some convertions happening. see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments#Default_conversions) for details

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel it gets promoted to an int iirc.

Comment: Ah, right. I hate C variadics.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel no, there is no UB. char is being converted to int as it as variadic function

Comment: You shouldn't make assumptions about the signedness of `char`. That is implementation-defined. `char` is a distinct type, separate from `signed char` and `unsigned char`, unlike other integral types that are implicitly signed.

Comment: @paddy it does not matter in this case https://godbolt.org/z/vn5YYzajE as if it is unsigned the program will behave exactly the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
printf("%02X", *ptr);
```

`*ptr` is being converted to `int` and printed as `int`

You need to use the correct printf format:

```
printf("%02hhX", *ptr);
```